# Seeding tables installing instructions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new at rails... I just want to know what is the complete procedure to populate seed data table in my project. As I use the following command:

`$ rake db:seed:dump MODELS=Country`

and I further have some more tables to for seed data.
Please define me the complete procedure to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your command in your question, you are using [seed_dump](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump) gem.

If you want to dump all table to populate the seed file, you can simply use:

```
$ rake db:seed:dump
```

If you want some tables, you can use a list of models (comma separated) like this to specify only the models you want to dump.

```
$ rake db:seed:dump MODELS=Country,User,Product
```

The output will be at db/seed.rb

Now, if you want to seed the data, you can simply use:

```
$ rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=[your_environment]
```

Please refer to more example at [seed_dump](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump) gem.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial step by step (for example model Country with name and population):

1) In `db/seeds.rb`

```
country_list = [
  [ "Russia", 143347059 ],
  [ "Germany", 81802000 ],
  [ "France", 60876136 ]
]

country_list.each do |name, population|
  Country.create( name: name, population: population )
end
```

2) Run `rake db:seed`

3) Thats all. In your Country table we have 3 countries. Congratulations!

Several resources about data seed:

1. [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data)
2. [ASCIIcast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data)
3. [Rails Best Practices](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/20-isolating-seed-data)

Comment: I want to know the complete procedure to do that all for seed data in the tables

Answer (score 0):

Simply we can rake db:seed

Otherwise
  http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data?view=asciicast